# How can I find the index of objects with length of 1 in a list?

Tags: r

I have a list of objects and each object is of varying lengths (containing 1 through n elements). How can I find the index of the objects with a length of 1?

I have tried:

```
lapply(list,function(x) x[which(length(x)==1)])
```

This correctly identifies the objects having a length of one, but does not give the numerical value representing their index within the list.

Comment: Your `lapply` runs the function on each element of an object called `list`, and returns which elements of **each element** has length 1. I think. You can use lapply this way: `unlist(lapply(mylist, length))` (PS don't name objects with the same name as R functions, like `list`) but `lengths` does that for you as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `lengths()` function to get the length of each element in the list, compare the result with 1 for the logical indices, then wrap with `which()` to get the numeric indices.

```
which(lengths(list) == 1)
```

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
(x <- replicate(3, sample(5, sample(3))))
# [[1]]
# [1] 5
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 4
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 3

which(lengths(x) == 1)
# [1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

May have slight syntactic errors, but generally speaking this is what you can do:

```
#instantiate indexes vector here
list.length <- length(list)
for (i in 1:list.length) {
    if (length(list[i])==1) {
        indexes <- c(indexes, i)
    }
}
```